# Building group-subgroup dropdown list in plsql

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracleforms

I have one table which holds **ID**, **GROUP_NAME** and **PARENT_GROUP_ID**. I am trying to create two drop down lists: first will have all group names that have **parent_group_id** as null, after first ddl is selected(or just default value selected) the values in the second ddl should all have the **PARENT_GROUP_ID** column to be equal to the the id of the first selected group. so far I have created data block with 2 poplists, and on 'when-new-form-instance' I am populating first ddl with

```
DECLARE
 rg_groups RecordGroup; 
 rg_group_name VARCHAR2(5) := 'GNAME'; 
 plist_ID Item := Find_Item(':GROUPS.GROUP_NAME'); 
 nDummy NUMBER;
BEGIN 
  rg_groups := Find_Group(rg_group_name); 
 -- Delete any existing Group first 
  IF NOT Id_Null(rg_groups) THEN 
    Delete_Group(rg_groups); 
  END IF;
 -- Now create a Record Group using a SQL query 
  -- Your Query must have a Label and a Value (two Columns) 
  -- and the data types must match your item type 
  rg_groups := Create_Group_From_Query(rg_group_name,'SELECT group_name, 
  to_char(ID) FROM GROUPS WHERE PARENT_GROUP_ID IS NULL'); 
  -- Clear the existing List 
  Clear_List(plist_ID); 
  -- Populate the Record Group 
  nDummy := Populate_Group(rg_groups); 
  -- Populate the List Item 
  Populate_List(':GROUPS.GROUP_NAME',rg_groups);
END;
```

And on 'post-change' trigger of the first poplist item, populate the second ddl:

```
DECLARE
 rg_groups RecordGroup; 
 rg_group_name VARCHAR2(5) := 'GPARENT_NAME'; 
 plist_ID Item := Find_Item(':GROUPS.PARENT_GROUP_ID'); 
 nDummy NUMBER;
BEGIN 
  rg_groups := Find_Group(rg_group_name); 
  -- Delete any existing Group first 
  IF NOT Id_Null(rg_groups) THEN 
    Delete_Group(rg_groups); 
  END IF;
   -- Now create a Record Group using a SQL query 
   -- Your Query must have a Label and a Value (two Columns) 
   -- and the data types must match your item type 
   rg_groups := Create_Group_From_Query(rg_group_name,'SELECT group_name, to_char(ID) FROM GROUPS WHERE PARENT_GROUP_ID = ' || :GROUPS.ID); 
   -- Clear the existing List 
   Clear_List(plist_ID); 
 -- Populate the Record Group 
 nDummy := Populate_Group(rg_groups); 
 -- Populate the List Item 
 Populate_List(':GROUPS.PARENT_GROUP_ID',rg_groups);
END;
```

However I feel that the part `WHERE PARENT_GROUP_ID = ' || :GROUPS.ID` is wrong because I didn't even fill the ID, and I need to extract it from the previous ddl, and this is where I am stuck, I don't quite understand how this works in oracle forms. I hope I can get some easily understandable advice on which way to take, Thanks!

Comment: also was a problem with the length of `rg_group_name `, it should be a bit longer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A pop-list typically has two columns - displayed label and value stored to item.

Your first pop-list is on `GROUPS.GROUP_NAME` item, shows group names and stores group ids. It means when user select a group, its id is stored to `GROUPS.GROUP_NAME` and your second pop-list is populated by wrong value.

Simply remove your first pop-list from `GROUPS.GROUP_NAME` and create it on `GROUPS.ID` item.

BTW: don´t use a colon, when you reference an item by name. `Find_Item(':GROUPS.GROUP_NAME')` is bad, `Find_Item('GROUPS.GROUP_NAME')` is right.

Comment: hm I understand what you mean, but how will poplist understand that i need to show the name of the group and having value of id instead of showing the id's?

Comment: It depends on column order in select - the first one is label, second one is value